# MSSQL: What happens when an error occurs during trigger execution?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, triggers, atomic

Regarding Update and Insert triggers for MS SQL Server, is there a way to make them atomic?  In other words, if an error occurs during the trigger, is it possible to automatically roll back the original insert or update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After triggers are automatically part of the insert/update/delete atomic DML statement on a table.

You simply issue ROLLBACK TRAN in the trigger to rollback all work in the trigger and the original I/U/D statement. The outermost tran is also rolled back if there is one.

**Important**

Rollback in a trigger for SQL 2000 and earlier aborts the batch. No code after the offending I/U/D will run. [See Erland great article](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-II.html#triggers) and [another](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#triggercontext)

For SQL 2005 with TRY/CATCH, execution will go to the CATCH block and your batch (aka stored proc etc) will exit normally.

See [Rollbacks and Commits in Stored Procedures and Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187844(SQL.90).aspx). The trigger and TRY/CATCH interation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article in MSDN that talks about triggers and transactions, located here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164032.aspx

Basically, you want to use transactions to make the operation atomic.